# Switching links to css via PHP

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement

My idea is to switch multiple links to CSS files, if special URL was detected. But I have a trouble: my code includes only css in the first if..else statement. And it doesn't depend on the URL.

Here is my code.
http://pastebin.com/Jm3QFDmH

**ported from pastebin**

```
<?php
// get first folder in URL
$f_folder = substr(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), "/"));
//get full directory structure from URL for current page
$full_path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
//css for account
if ($f_folder='account') {
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mainstyle/common.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mainstyle/account.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<?php 
} elseif ($f_folder='signin'||$f_folder='signup'||$full_path='/account/resetPassword'||$full_path='/account/logout') {
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mainstyle/login-signup.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<?php
} else {
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mainstyle/common.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Where is mistake?

Comment: Try to print your `$f_folder` to see if there's a problem.

Comment: @NikolaK. I tried and it works

Comment: the if should be: if ($f_folder == 'account')

Comment: @Alf Thank you, problem solved. I forgot that it must be comparison. Post this as an answer.

Comment: Hi, try writing your code this way: $fullPaths=array('/account/resetPassword','/account/logout'); $signupPaths=array('signin','signup'); and then your if is simpler if('account' == $f_folder) { ... } else if(in_array($f_folder,$signupPaths) || in_array($full_path,$fullPaths)) {} abstract those out to variables so the code is easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if and elseif, should have == comparison operator , not = assignment

Answer (score 2):

Line 7 should be

```
if ($f_folder=='account') {
```